# setText() of TextView in list_row.xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have:

1. One `MyListActivity class extends ListActivity` `setContentView(R.layout.mylist)`;
2. Two xml files: `mylist.xml` and `list_row.xml`.
3. `mylist.xml` is the layout and `list_row.xml` is how each row looks like.
4. `list_row.xml` contains 3 `TextViews(t1,t2,t3)`.

I want to change some text of t2 in `MyListActivity` class. Because the content view is mylist.xml so I can't simply use `findViewById`. So I used `LayoutInflater`.

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    textView2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.t2);
    textView2.setText("ccccc");
```

The problem is that the text of t2 is never changed. I have tried many times and the text remains the text I set in the `list_row.xml`. I can't figure out why.. Could someone help please. Thanks!

=====**Solution**:=====

Create my own `SimpleCursorAdapter` class and override the `getView()` method.

```
private class MySimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    Cursor c;
    public MySimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        this.c = c;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
        TextView textview1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        textView1.setText(c.getString(1));// whatever should be in textView1
        textView2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        textView2.setText("ccccc");
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

The `super.getView(position, convertView, parent);` is quite important because if I don't have that line, `textView1` will always show the value of first row(e.g. if `textView1` shows the id, then this is always 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the `TextView` text you will have to do it in the adapter of the `ListView`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have a SimpleCursorAdaper and I have been `public View newView (Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)` which "Inflates view(s) from the specified XML file" and `public abstract View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` which I can inflate from XML file. But in the API, it doesn't say how to inflate. Could you provide a link to an example? Thanks a lot

Comment: Another question. Is the root view the list view and each row would be a child of the list view?

Comment: Yeah, problem solved! Just added `MySimpleCursorAdapter` and override `getView()` and change the text there. It turned out that `getView()` is called by the adapter for each row. Thanks!

Comment: @Dongminator If you want to make any changes to your rows you must implement your own adapter and override the `getView()`(the entire purpose of this method is to give you a row when the `ListView` ask for it) method to change how the rows look and what data you put in that partivcular row. You said you use `SimpleCursorAdapter` so you can also take a look  at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder.html .

Comment: one last question: now I can change the text of textview2 but text1 of each row is never drawn. Why is that?

Comment: @Dongminator Without  seeing the code of your adapter i can say anything, but you're probably not doing something right in the method getView().

Comment: `@slukian` problem solved! I simply use the cursor passed into my own adapter class and use the cursor to get the string I need. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Best way to change your textview is in `getView()`. See [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List4.html) example to get more insight.